# Trying to split a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, split

Hello I am trying to compare this list of dictionaries:
Call this list Animals:

```
[{'Fishs=16': 'Fishs=16',
  'Birds="6"': 'Birds="6"',
  'Dogs=5': 'Dogs=5',
  'Bats=10': 'Bats=10',
  'Tigers=11': 'Tigers=11',
  'Cats=4': 'Cats=4'},
 {'Cats=40': 'Cats=40',
  'Tigers': 'Tigers = 190',
  'Birds=4': 'Birds=4',
  'Bats': 'Bats = Null',
  'Fishs': 'Fishs = 24',
  'Dogs': 'Dogs = 10'}]
```

I want to make the list look like this

```
[{'Tigers': 'Tigers=11',
  'Dogs': 'Dogs=5',
  'Cats': 'Cats=4',
  'Bats': 'Bats=10',
  'Fishs': 'Fishs=16',
  'Birds': 'Birds="6"'},
 {'Tigers': 'Tigers=190',
  'Dogs': 'Dogs=10',
  'Cats': 'Cats=40',
  'Bats': 'Bats=Null',
  'Fishs': 'Fishs=24',
  'Birds': 'Birds=4'}]
```

so that I can compare it to this other list:

```
{'Tigers': '19',
 'Dogs': '10',
 'Cats': '40',
 'Bats': '10',
 'Fishs': '234',
 'Birds': '3'}
```

Heres the code i've tried to use inorder to split the list:

```
animals = []
for d in setData:
    animals.append({k: v.split('=')[1] for k, v in d.items()})
```

however It will not split the list since my keys in the dictionaries are in this format `Dogs=4` rather than `Dogs = 4`. I need to be able to split this list even if they are in that format.

On a completely different side note, once this part of the code is fixed I need to figure out how to compare the data from these keys against each other.

for example: Lets say I have `Dogs="23"` and the compared list is `Dogs="50"` According to my code this should be Incorrect, but due to the quotes ("23") it says it is, it does not compare the value inside. This is the code i have to compare:

```
correct_parameters = dict(re.match(r'(\w*)="?(\d*)"?', s).group(1, 2) for s in dataDefault[1:])
print correct_parameters
count = 0
while (count < (len(setNames))):
    for number, item in enumerate(animals, 1):
        print setNames[count]
        count = count + 1
        for param, correct in correct_parameters.items():
            if item[param] == correct:
                print('{} = {} which is correct'.format(param, correct))
```

However for now I am just trying to fix the list split issue i am having.

Comment: BTW the plural of `Fish` is `Fish` not `Fishs`

Comment: Why are you trying to get it into the form `[{'Tigers': 'Tigers=11',...` rather than the more useful looking `[{'Tigers': 11,` or even `[{'Tigers': '11',`?

Comment: @or1426 thats what the code does. Look at the `animals = []`

Comment: @or1426 the issue is that it doesnt spilt `tiger=11` only if its `tiger = 11` it needs a whitespace but for the sake of my code i can not add whitespaces

Comment: @JeanP I don't understand why it doesn't split. Try running this through the python interpreter `'a=1'.split('=')`. On both version 2.7.10 and 3.4.3 on my computer the list ['a', '1'] is returned. If the issue is that the strings in the list have whitespace after them then use the 'strip()` method that strings have to remove this.

Comment: You could make your example shorter

Comment: @PeterWood Which Example? The Dictionary or the Quotation example?

Comment: @or1426 It does work with that piece of code however I am not sure why my list isn't.

Comment: @JeanP You need to make more obvious the link between the given input and the desired output. If there was less data it would be easier to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lst = [{'Fishs=16': 'Fishs=16', 'Birds="6"': 'Birds="6"', 'Dogs=5': 'Dogs=5', 'Bats=10': 'Bats=10', 'Tigers=11': 'Tigers=11', 'Cats=4': 'Cats=4'}, {'Cats=40': 'Cats=40', 'Tigers': 'Tigers = 190', 'Birds=4': 'Birds=4', 'Bats': 'Bats = Null', 'Fishs': 'Fishs = 24', 'Dogs': 'Dogs = 10'}]

# for each element in that list, loop with index
for idx, val in enumerate(lst):
    # create temp object
    o = {}
    # loop the dictionary
    for k,v in val.iteritems():
        # if = is found in key
        if '=' in k:
            # change the key
            k = k.split('=')[0]
        # insert to temp object
        o[k] = v
    # change the temp object to current element in the list
    lst[idx] = o
```

Comment: This worked great, How could i edit this so for a future reference I can get the following instead: `[{'Dogs':'5', .... `

Comment: I intentionally commented the code so you can perhaps learn. but... https://gist.github.com/limtaesu/d7bb5662122a045e58b0

Answer (score 0):

Just `strip` the string after you split it:

```
 >>> [v.strip() for v in "   a   =    b    ".split('=')]
 ['a', 'b']
```